# bitcoin-cli fails with auth error

Tags: bitcoind, client

I run it like the below.

```
bitcoind -datadir=/Users/varunvb/Downloads -conf=/Users/varunvb/Downloads/bitcoin.conf -daemon
```

When I run (Using the user name and password as in the config file)

```
bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=<USER> -rpcpassword=<PWD> getinfo
```

I get 
error: `incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)`

I see the below in the debug log

```
ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1
```

My bitcoin.conf file looks like this:

```
-e
rpcuser=<USER>
rpcpassword=<PWD>
```

Comment: What are the contents of `bitcoin.conf`? Is there another `bitcoin-core` instance running at the same time on the same machine?

Comment: Thanks David for replying! The content inside config file is as below  -e rpcuser=<USER>
rpcpassword=<PWD>  that's it. And no there're no other instances running apart from bitcoind i showed in the question

Comment: Remove that `-e` before `rpcuser`. Please consult [this sample configuration](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Sample_Bitcoin.conf).

Comment: bitcoin-cli can read rpcuser and rpcpassword out of your config file. Just pass `-conf=/Users/varunvb/Downloads/bitcoin.conf` to bitcoin-cli.

Comment: @NickODell has a point. Just call `bitcoin-cli -conf=/Users/varunvb/Downloads/bitcoin.conf -datadir=/Users/varunvb/Downloads getinfo` and that should be it.

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis removing -e form the config worked! Thanks!

Comment: @NickODell I supply the directory as a command line parameter and it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

bitcoin-cli can read rpcuser and rpcpassword out of your config file. Just run it like this:

```
bitcoin-cli -conf=/Users/varunvb/Downloads/bitcoin.conf -datadir=/Users/varunvb/Downloads getinfo
```

Also, remove the `-e` from your bitcoin.conf.